# How to force fail a dag after x number of time?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to force fail a dag after say 3 hours have passed.
I have a dag that is scheduled for 2am and one that is scheduled for 6am. I want the 2am dag to stop and give precedence to the one scheduled at 6am.

1. I have already tried using `execution_timeout`
2. I have tried using `dagrun_timeout` keeps running as there are no other dags to run within the first dag.

NOTE: This is like a cross-dag dependency where I want to give preference to a dag during certain hours

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically stopping a dag like I wanted to do above is not possible. I solved my issue, giving priority to a dag by assigning a larger pool to it.